# Doctrine/Symfony - Conflicts between entities. Trying to make relations. I get an error

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I always get an exception with my entities. I tried to play with them. I checked on google which relation is the most appropriate for my entities... But I couldn't find the best configuration.

I'm making a website where you can create a simple post and where you can create some albums.

3 Entities : Album / Poste / Pictures

In Album I have a Pictures Array, and I have a Pictures array in Poste as well.

A user can have multiple albums.
Inside the Album Entity, I did put the user to keep a reference.

```
/**
* Album
*
* @ORM\Table(name="album")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\AlbumRepository")
*/

class Album
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/** 
 ** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 ** @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false) 
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="creationDate", type="datetime")
 */
private $creationDate;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="modificationDate", type="datetime")
 */
private $modificationDate;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\Picture", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="album")
 */
 private $pictures;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->creationDate = new \Datetime();
    $this->modificationDate = new \Datetime();
}
 // Get and set
}
```

When a user subscribe on the website, I create a default album called Upload that I want to keep in the user class.

This is what I tried to do :

```
/**
* User
*    
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser  
{
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
 protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\Album", cascade={"persist"})
 */
 protected $albumUpload;

 // Get and set
}
```

My Poste entity with the pictures array :

```
/**
 * Poste
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="poste")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Moodress\Bundle\PosteBundle\Entity\PosteRepository")
 */
class Poste
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    private $description;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\Picture", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="poste")
     */
     private $pictures;

     // Getters and setters
}
```

My Picture entity :

```
/**
 * Picture
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="picture")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\PictureRepository")
 */
class Picture
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
     ** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     ** @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false) 
     */
    private $user;

     /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

I have this error : `Undefined index: album in /Users/Sandro/sites/moodress-website/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1608.` 
This error appears directly when I serialize any entity that has a user object...

In the log :

```
at ErrorHandler->handle('8', 'Undefined index: album', '/Users/Sandro/sites/moodress-website/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php', 
'1608', array('assoc' => array('fieldName' => 'pictures', 'mappedBy' => 'album', 
'targetEntity' => 'Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\Picture', 
'cascade' => array('persist'), 'orphanRemoval' => false, 'fetch' => '2', 
'type' => '4', 'inversedBy' => null, 'isOwningSide' => false, 'sourceEntity' => 'Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\Album', 'isCascadeRemove' => false, 
'isCascadePersist' => true, 'isCascadeRefresh' => false, 'isCascadeMerge' => false, 
'isCascadeDetach' => false), 'sourceEntity' => object(Album), 'offset' => null, 
'limit' => null, 'criteria' => array())) in /Users/Sandro/sites/moodress-website/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1608
```

I don't know what is wrong with my entities. Any help?

Comment: What is the name of column in you `user` table that corresponds to `albumUpload` field?

Comment: The name of the column `albumUpload` field is `albumUpload_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

```
'Undefined index: album'
```

results from this annotation in the `Album` class.

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *      targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\Picture",
 *      cascade={"persist"}, 
 *      mappedBy="album"
 *  )
 */
```

You have set mappedBy to `album` but there is no `$album` property in your `Picture` class.

Add this to your `Picture` class and clear your cache.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *      targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\Album",
 *      inversedBy="pictures"
 *  )
 */
protected $album;
```

Comment: The problem is that I have `$pictures` in `Album` and I have a `$pictures` array in `Poste`. It won't make conflicts?

Comment: This won't cause any conflicts ... Why shouldn't `Poste` have a relation to `Picture` ... and `Album`, too ?

Comment: I have this error now when I serialize : `Expected object but got array. Do you have the wrong @Type mapping or could this be a Doctrine many-to-many relation?`